# Intermitent Hanging/Freezing of Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, freeze

I have written my first Website with Vb2010 using C# and ASP.net. When I run my website on my local desktop where the code resides, I don't have any problems. However, after publishing the website and testing from a couple of desktops, I notice that the website freezes intermittently.

What I noticed on testing:

1. The freeze was sometimes triggered by untrapped errors, so I went
   through my entire code making sure to trap any errors. Now I don't
   get those.
2. I have a few parent pages which call pop up pages when
   the user clicks a button. The popup pages allow the entry of new
   records which are then populated into a grid on the parent page.
   I noticed that if the user opens the pop up, enters and closes
   the pop six times, it causes the entire website to freeze and the
   only way to continue is to close the browser and restart.
3. Sometimes the freeze just happens and when I try to replicate the
   actions just before the freeze, the freeze is not replicated.

My question might be irritating, but please I'm a novice here.

Edited: 24/02/14
I've done a little testing with Task Manager for Chrome and Resource Manager. I have a couple of parent pages with update panel enclosed gridviews which display any records in the db table. The update panel is triggered by a timer. The parent pages also have an 'Add New Record' button where a popup page is called to allow new records to be inserted into the db. When the user clicks 'Add New Record', my timer is enabled to allow the gridview to be refreshed so the user can see the record has been added.

I picked up during my testing that my timers are causing network traffic every time they refresh the grid. There's about 13kb being transferred every second. I think if I can figure out how to access and disable the timer from the popup page once the user clicks the back button to return to the parent page, one problem would be resolved. I can't figure out how to call the timer from the popup page though.

I'm not sure if this is the actual problem causing the freeze, but it's a step closer to figuring it out. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'freeze'? Do you mean that the browser stopped responding or your website stopped working?

Comment: I'm not sure we can help you without looking at your code.  Is there a way for you to diagnose memory consumption?  it sounds like your server is OOMing.

Comment: By freeze you mean "waiting for ..." or what?

Comment: By freeze, I mean nothing responds to clicking. Buttons become unclickable. I can't even log out cause the logout link is unclickable. I have to literally close my browser session and re-start it again. @Chris the problem is I don't know what is causing the freeze, so I wouldn't know which part of my code to show you. And what do you mean OOMing?

Comment: I'm gonna use the Resource Monitor and will come back to you. Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you have some dodgy JavaScript. Check your browser console for errors (usually F12).

Comment: I've done a little testing with Task Manager for Chrome and Resource Manager. I picked up that my pages with timers always has network activity. I have a gridview on my parent page. When my user clicks add new record, I enable my timer to allow the gridview to be updated so the user can see the record has been added. I'm not sure if this is the actual problem causing the freeze, but I'm closer to figuring it out. What I'm struggling to figure out is how to disable the timer once the user closes the popup page. And there doesn't seem a way to call the parent timer from the popup page.